# How to debug failed checksums/flipped bits in TCP packets?

Tags: linux, networking, ssl, tcp

A web application we maintain recently encountered a very weird problem: three out of four virtual machines on two physical hosts had trouble connecting to the server of our payment provider via HTTPS. Debugging this issue took me on an interesting tour down the OSI stack:

1. on the application level it seemed like the HTTPS request timed out.
2. using `openssl s_client`, I found out that the SSL handshake failed
3. dumping traffic with tcpdump and inspecting it with Wireshark, I noticed that for failing handshakes, all packets from the server after the initial SYN/ACK had invalid TCP checksums. Comparing the packet contents with successful handshakes, I found out that at least one bit had flipped. The server then tries to retransmit the packets (again with invalid checksums) and closes the connection after 60 seconds.

Neither our payment provider nor our hosting company has been very helpful diagnosing this problem. Luckily the problem has gone away after a couple of hours.

However, this "solution" leaves me very unhappy. I would like to know:

1. what are possible causes for this behavior?
2. how can this problem be diagnosed any further if it occurs again in the future?

Virtual machines are running Debian 7 on KVM.

Comment: If you're not already I would recommend that you set up a SPAN port for running Wireshark. The first question I would like to know the answer is 'is it happening at their end or ours?'. In transit is also a possibility, of course.  And you can then also make sure TCP offloading is disabled on the capturing machine without messing with the settings on your production system.

Comment: Try to use simple ping test. Use it with two parameters `-p` to assign packet data pattern and `-s` to assign packet size as in bad packet. You'll look for a pattern with which ping will be bad. Then do `traceroute` to know all routers between your tested hosts. Then do same ping command to finded routers hosts.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Will try these out when the problem occurs again

Answer (score 0):

So using this article as refference: https://www.networkdatapedia.com/single-post/2017/09/13/TCP-Checksum-Error-Case-Study

I will try to answer and clarify:

> 1. what are possible causes for this behavior?

There are few possible causes:

- TCP checksum offloading. As already mentioned - is a technique where CPU does not calculate the TCP checksum but leaves this to NIC. The NIC may calculate it incorrectly.
- faulty layer 3 device. This needs to be at layer 3 as TCP checksum errors may occur after a successfull Ethernet CRC check - which is more robust than TCP checksum. You can therefore eliminate faulty cables or connectors.
- man in the middle packet payload manipulation. This is very unlikely since man in the middle is able to calculate a proper TCP checksum and put it to the packet.

> 2. how can this problem be diagnosed any further if it occurs again in the future?

using the mentioned article as a reference you should set up at least two traffic capture locations that should include VM and also bare metal / router interfaces.

Depending on the network architecture - you may find a faulty L3 networking component. Unfortunaltely the network may be faulty upstream so make sure to caputer packets as they leave and enter your controlled environment to make sure.

As to my personal networking experience - a fully saturated network may lead to protocols such as SSH or HTTPS to be unable to establish a connection. Make sure there's enough bandwidth available and that the hosts in question are able to respond in a timely manner.

Comment: The link contained in this answer no longer exists.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20201126005403/https://www.networkdatapedia.com/post/2017/09/13/tcp-checksum-error-case-study